# É possível alterar um tipo de tabela definido pelo usuário?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Eu criei um tipo de tabela para usar em algumas procedures, e após a criação das procedures, percebi que preciso alterar alguns dos tipos das colunas.

Existe alguma instrução para alterar um tipo de tabela?

Estou tentando evitar deletar o tipo e criar de novo para evitar problemas com ordem de exeução dos scripts...
Tentei dar drop e criar de novo, mas como existem procedures que usam esse tipo, o SQL Server impede a execução do script.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MeuTipo] AS TABLE(
[Campo1] [int] NULL,
[Campo2] [varchar](512) NULL,
[Campo3] [datetime] NULL,
[Campo4] [varchar](512) NULL,
[Campo5] [bigint] NULL)
GO
```

Comment: Consegue colocar o script de criação do tipo para verificarmos?

Comment: Adicionei como edição

Comment: E o que você quer alterar nesse tipo?

Comment: A alteração no meu caso seria o comprimento do varchar de uma das colunas, mas extendo a minha pergunta para outras alterações também, como novas colunas/remoção de colunas etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe a possibilidade de alterar diretamente o tipo. O que você pode fazer é utilizar a `sp_rename` para renomear o tipo com um nome temporário, criá-lo novamente com as novas definições e atualizar as dependências utilizando a `procedure` `sp_refreshsqlmodule`:

```
-- Renomeia o tipo
EXEC sys.sp_rename 'dbo.MeuTipo', 'MeuTipoTEMP';
GO

-- Cria o tipo com as novas definições
CREATE TYPE dbo.MeuTipo AS TABLE(
  Campo1 INT NULL,
  Campo2 VARCHAR(512) NULL,
  Campo3 DATETIME NULL,
  Campo4 VARCHAR(512) NULL,
  Campo5 BIGINT NULL
);
GO

-- Percorre as dependências atualizando-as
DECLARE @Nome NVARCHAR(1000);

DECLARE cursor_referencias CURSOR FOR
  SELECT referencing_schema_name + '.' + referencing_entity_name
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('dbo.MeuTipo', 'MeuTipoTEMP');
OPEN cursor_referencias;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_referencias INTO @Nome;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  EXEC sys.sp_refreshsqlmodule @Name = @Nome;

  FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_referencias INTO @Nome;
END;
CLOSE cursor_referencias;
DEALLOCATE cursor_referencias;
GO

DROP TYPE MeuTipoTEMP;
GO
```

---

> [**`sp_rename`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188351(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Altera o nome de um objeto criado pelo usuário no banco de dados atual. Esse objeto pode ser uma tabela, índice, coluna, tipo de dados de alias ou tipo de dados CLR definido pelo usuário do Microsoft .NET Framework Common Language Runtime.

---

> [**`sp_refreshsqlmodule`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb326754(v=sql.110).aspx)
>
> Atualiza os metadados do procedimento armazenado não associado a esquema, da função definida pelo usuário, da exibição, do gatilho DML, do gatilho DDL de nível de banco de dados ou do gatilho DDL de nível de servidor especificado no banco de dados atual. Metadados persistentes desses objetos, como tipos de dados de parâmetros, podem ficar desatualizados devido a atualizações em seus objetos subjacentes.

---

**Referência:** [**Altering user-defined table types in SQL Server**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30403159/3388148)